# $http.post - Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, http-headers

I'm using angular js.
I have a form where I'm asking the user to enter URL Basic Auth details i.e., username and password for HTTP POST (like PostMan)

I need to check whether the credentials work or not.

I came up with the following code:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: $scope.serviceConfig.url, headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
})
    .success(function(res)
    {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .error(function(res)
    {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

I get the following error:

> cannot load https://posttestserver.com/post.php. Request header field
>   Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

1. Is putting the Auth base64 inside the headers a right way?
2. Is this the server's problem or am I doing something wrong?
3. Is there any other way to test the credentials?
4. Is there any other server where I can test Auth? I found https://httpbin.org/ but it only supports HTTP GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed set the authorization header in the correct way. However, postservertest.com has prohibited that header from being used via [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebAccessControl#Setting_.22Access-Control-Allow-Methods.22_for_a_particular_Agent):

```
$ HEAD http://posttestserver.com
200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 15:26:58 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So in summary, your code is correct. It is just the server unwilling to accept your request. You can try [requestb.in](http://requestb.in).

Comment: You mean http://requestb.in  right? If yes, please edit. I tried editing yours but changes need at least 6 chars

Comment: Can you tell me whats this output from?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It really is requestb.in. That output is from a little utility called `HEAD`, which is issuing `HEAD` requests against given URLs. `curl -I` should achieve the same.

Comment: I'm getting similar error:    
cannot load http://requestb.in/16jgni71. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: But when I POST using postman, I receive `OK` response. And the auth header is seen in requestbin. But not from my code. `Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization` is seen when POSTed from my code.

Comment: The browser has CrossOrigin security on. That is why your code isn't working in the browser and working in postman.

You need the server (here: requestb.in ) to accept a pre-flight request (OPTIONS) and in response send `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with your custom header value.